# Work around for “Couldn’t load PyQt” error with QGIS 3.0.3 on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: qgis, pyqt

I am working with a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 and installed QGIS using https://qgis.org/debian. I get the following error when I launch QGIS:

```
Couldn't load PyQt.
Python support will be disabled.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.10' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.so)
Python version:
3.6.5 (default, Apr  1 2018, 05:46:30) 
[GCC 7.3.0]

QGIS version:
3.0.3-Girona 'Girona', 8a899c8

Python path:
['/usr/share/qgis/python', '/home/ned/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python', '/home/ned/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins', '/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

A similar error has been reported as a bug (https://issues.qgis.org/issues/19040) but I haven’t seen a workaround.

I tried to install 2.18 (ltr) but apt-get failed with:

```
qgis : Depends: python-qgis (= 1:2.18.20+28bionic) but 1:3.1.0+git20180529+ad1fef9+28bionic is to be installed
```

Any suggestions on how to get QGIS working on Ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this error by installing PyQt5 using the Python package manager. If you remove the Python-managed PyQt5 and instead install the OS version, QGIS should launch. I have confirmed that an OS-managed PyQt5 ***is*** available on clean install of Ubuntu 18.04, and a/o June 1, 2018, both Ubuntu repositories and PyPI are providing PyQt 5.10.1.

Remove PyQt5 with:

```
sudo pip3 uninstall PyQt5
```

You can confirm that PyQt5 is available to the system Python with:

```
apt-cache policy python3-pyqt5
```

Comment: Didn't work for me (Linux Mint 18). After uninstalling using `pip3` QGIS didn't launch at all. I reinstalled PyQt5 and started working again, but with the same error.

Comment: I have done that in Ubuntu 18.04 and I can run now QGIS without a problem. 
But I need Qt library for some script which I wrote in python and I am trying to run with Pycharm. What should I do? :/ With PyQt I can't use PyQgis, with PyQGIS I can't use PyQt. :/